# Geração de relatórios em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, relatório

Gostaria de saber uma biblioteca para geração de relatórios no JavaScript, e com servidor NodeJS. Já pesquisei algumas coisas mas nada se adequou muito ao que eu preciso, pode ser tanto a geração de relatórios através das tabelas renderizadas no html como buscar os dados no DB.

Comment: Normalmente, o relatório é gerado client-side com algumas bibliotecas em JavaScript. O que você deveria fazer é: No seu servidor, criar end-points que forneçam os dados do relatório e no front-end montar um HTML e então transformar em PDF e etc

Comment: se você usa node e npm, basta procurar pelo tipo de relatório que queiras gerar, por exemplo esse package https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx já cobre quase tudo que precisa

Comment: Já consegui achar uma biblioteca chamada pdfMake que cria pdf's, agradeço muito a ajuda de vocês